# Calendar display with custom table

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I am trying to show a calendar page with records stored in a custom table, using the Calendar module.

The table has been integrated with Views using `hook_views_data`. I also implemented `hook_date_views_extra_tables` and `hook_date_views_fields` to identity the relevant date fields to the Date module.

So far, I can create a new View with Calendar format (style plugin). When I add the Date: Date contextual filter (argument), I am able to see the field I specified in the `hook_date_views_fields`. So far so good.

Now when I save the view and show it, no calendar shows. When I get back to edit the view, the Date argument has been replaced with a "Broken/missing handler" notice.

Has anyone succeeded to show a calendar from a custom table?

N.B. [This issue was created for the same purpose](http://drupal.org/node/1329894) but it looks like the OP did not pursue it (or at least did not update it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this problem was that the date argument handler was crashing. I had placed the implementations of the date hooks inside mymodule.views.inc, instead of mymodule.module. Duh!